# Android - Value Added Listener causes app to crash

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read a list of users from a DatabaseReference, but the code causes the app to crash.

```
firebase.child(subject).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       Map<String,String> td = (HashMap<String,String>) snapshot.getValue();
       users = (List)td.keySet();
   }
   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
       Toast.makeText(context,"Internet connection failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
});
```

Comment: is it casting error? paste logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to call the data is

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener)
```

Inside onDataChange,

```
String string = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
textView.setText(string);
```

That .child() is declared above outside your onCreate,

```
DatabaseReference db = Master.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference text1 = db.child("databseValueNameYouGiveInConcolse");
```

Comment: @Pang there's nothing wrong in all your edited code. You just made the 2 lines, become 1. Apparently it didnt affect the codes.